# git push error: the requested URL returned error 400

Tags: git, github, git-push

I am new to Git and I am trying to to push a Java project to Github using Git Bash.

This is what I did:

- created a Blog repository in GitHub
- in Git Bash

  $ cd C:/Users/Alessandro/workspace/BLOG

  $ echo "# Blog" >> README.md

  $ git add –-all

  $ git commit -m "Initial commit"

  $ git remote add origin https://github.com/alerossi82/Blog

  $ git push -u origin master

But when I do the push, this is the result I get:

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username/repository/': The requested URL returned error: 400

I read somewhere this is could be a login problem, but I checked my config in GitBash and the username and email match with GitHub. 
When I commit the push, I I am logged in to my GitHub account and I do not receive any insert password request from GitBash.

Then I tried to push the project directly from Eclipse, but this failed as well,  in fact when I push the changes I receive the message:
- master >> master [rejected - non-fast-forward]

I am totally lost, I think all the step are correct however it looks like my local and remote repositories don't want to talk to each other, and I have no idea why.

Any help?

Comment: Why have you added `JAVA` as one of the Tags? You might want to do a Pull first, make changes and then push it.

Comment: ok, as I wrote I'm new to Git, but if I understood it well, a Pull is a request to propose to merge the changes in a branch into the master branch, is it correct? The fact is, I did not do any change to my project, therefore I did not create any alternative branch; I simply would like to pull all the files from my project to the remote repository in the master branch. Does it make sense or I am missing something?

Comment: Pull Request won't come into picture if you are pushing your changes directly to the master branch. If you are working on a feature branch then you'll have to create a Pull request to merge it on to your develop/master branch.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem and it turned out that I had some issues with my `.gitconfig` file since I had earlier run `git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"` and later `git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf "git@github.com:"` which added both lines to my .gitconfig file. So all I did was clean my .gitconfig file using vim in my terminal`(Iterm)` :

`$ vi $HOME/.gitconfig`

Then removed the unwanted lines from the `.gitconfig` file using vim editor. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the

```
 git add . -A
```

before the commit so no files were added

---

```
cd C:/Users/Alessandro/workspace/BLOG
echo "# Blog" >> README.md

# Here you need to run the git add command 
git add -A .

git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/alerossi82/Blog
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: in fact, I did add the file, I simply forgot to write a line in my post. I've just updated it, thx.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `.git` part, which is important. The url you are adding corresponds to the web page you view on GitHub, not the git repository. You should do:

`$ git remote add origin https://github.com/alerossi82/Blog.git`

Also, if this is your own repository, you probably want to use the SSH url instead of the HTTPS url: 
`$ git remote add origin git@github.com:alerossi82/Blog.git`

This will make your everyday life easier, as you can use an ssh key for authentication instead of typing your GitHub password every time. More info on GitHub urls [here](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/).

Answer (score 0):

You should fist check what files, you have changes and are ready to be committed, using :

```
git status
```

If you saw any changed files, stage them for committing, using :

```
git add .
```

Then commit your changes.

```
git commit -m "your commit message"
```

And finally :

```
git push -u origin master
```